# php twilio hang up not working by updating status

Tags: php, twilio-api

So im doing a ringless voicemail and have everything working except for the initial call is not hanging up. I've added a timeout of 5 seconds to it which ends the call but sometimes i still get a ring or a number called on my phone. Ive tried to hang up 2 ways.

```
$message = $this->client->calls($_REQUEST['CallSid'])->update(
    array(
        'url' => 'twilioxmlHangup.xml',
        "method" => "POST"
    )
);


<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Response>
<Say voice="alice">.</Say>
<Hangup/>
</Response>
```

I also tried

```
$message = $this->client->calls($_REQUEST['CallSid'])->update(array("status" => "completed"));
```

Im trying to cancel the call after i make my 2nd call and it doesn't seem to do anything. I found this which is similar but don't understand what needs to be done. [Twilio hangup call through REST API not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681064/twilio-hangup-call-through-rest-api-not-working)

Thank you

Comment: Could it be that the you can't actually `<Hangup/>` a call that is not answered yet? Have you tried with `<Reject/>`?